# Javascript Credential Management API Fetch integration with Credentials

Tags: javascript, html, credentials

Can someone please provide an example of, or explain how, an application server retrieves the "credentials" object (federated/password) when it is the target of a FETCH method: "POST", credentials: myLovelyPWDCredentials?

Does my RESTful Web-Service receive the values as form-encoded? Are they hidden in http headers? Only visible to HTTP Web-Servers that explicitly support credential management UAs by transparently pre-processing the credentials?

Sorry but I couldn't find the dev_server.py file on my Google VM and am struggling to understand how the same "credentials" are overloaded so that sometimes it is set to "same-domain" so that cookies are included with the Fetch and other times username,password,name,image, , ,

Yes it's a great idea that the credential values are not visible to my Javascript but my server code needs to work specific magic.

Cheers Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found detailed explanation [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/credential-management/#body-extraction)